# confusion about struct pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I wrote the following piece of code. I have a question: in these two line:

```
r1 = r;
r1 = new node();
```

I think that when `r1` becomes a new empty node, `r` should also be a new empty node because `r1=r` is a pointer assignment, so `r1` and `r` represent the same address. However I must be wrong because the result shows that `r` here was not changed. Could anybody explain it to me why `r` is not changed? Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node{
    int id;
    node *child;
};


int main()
{
    node *r = new node();
    node *r1 = new node();
    r->id = 100;

    r1 = r;
    r1 = new node();
    r1->child = r;

    cout << "r1 " << r1->id << endl;
    cout << "r1 child " << (r1->child)->id << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
r1 0
r1 child 100
```

Comment: Two pointers can point at the same thing but still be different pointers.

Comment: `r1 = r;`
`r1 = new node();`
So... `r1` is a brand new node. The output is completely expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is exactly that, a pointer--it points (refers to) something else.

I think in this case, it's probably easiest to understand things graphically. So, after you do:

```
node *r = new node();
node *r1 = new node();
r->id = 100;
```

The situation is roughly like this:

[image]

Then when you execute: `r1 = r;`, you get a situation like this:

[image]

Note that you've leaked the `node` that `r1` was pointing to (i.e., you no longer have a pointer to it, so you can't delete it any more).

Then when you do `r1 = new node();`: you get something like this:

[image]

Finally, after executing `r1->child = r;` you have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They cannot be the same. `r` and `r1` are two locations in the memory which can hold address to `node` (by definition in the code), so when you perform `r1 = r`, the value in those memory locations become the same (pointer value).

But, when you later perform `r1 = new node;` then the `new` returns a pointer to the newly created object, which is only stored in `r1` memory location. Since address in `r` location in the memory does not change, hence you see the results.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question: in these two line:  `r1 = r;r1 = new node();` I think that when `r1` becomes a new empty node, `r` should also be a new empty node because `r1=r` is a pointer assignment

Nope.  When you do `r1 = r;` all you are doing is setting the value of `r1` to the same value of `r`.  It does not link `r1` and `r` together and anything you change in `r1` to does nothing to `r`.

You should also note that `r1 = r;` causes a memory leak as `r1` no longer points to the node you originally created and you did not `delete` it before the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Marching through the code step by step may help explain what is happening.

```
    node *r = new node();
```

Create block of memory **A** and point `r` at **A**

```
    node *r1 = new node();
```

Create block of memory **B** and point `r1` at **B**

```
    r->id = 100;
```

Dereference `r` to locate **A**. `id` in **A** is set to 100

```
    r1 = r;
```

Point  `r1` at the same thing as `r`. `r1` now points to **A**. There is no linkage between **A** and **B**. Nothing is copied from **A** to **B**. `r1` is merely redirected to point **A** instead of **B**.

**B** no longer has any referrers and is lost. This is called a memory leak. `delete r1;` before reassigning to prevent this. Better, since **B** is never used, don't allocate it in the first place.

```
    r1 = new node();
```

Create block of memory **C** and point `r1` at **C**. As above, `r1` is directed to point at **C** instead of **A**. No copying or other side effects take place. There is no longer any association between `r1` and **A**. **A** is unchanged and `r` still points at **A**.

```
    r1->child = r;
```

Dereference `r1` to locate **C**. Point `child` in **C** at **A**.

```
    cout << "r1 " << r1->id << endl;
```

Dereference `r1` to locate **C**. Print out `id` in **C**. `id` in **C** has never been assigned a value, so using it is undefined behaviour. Any value may be printed, nothing may be printed, or the program may cause the computer to grow legs and eat the neighbour's cat, though this is unlikely.

```
    cout << "r1 child " << (r1->child)->id << endl;
```

Dereference `r1` to locate **C**. Dereference `child` in **C** to locate **A**. Print out `id` in **A**, 100.